# Google Sign in not working after first time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-signin

So, I have an iOS app that allows the user to login via Google. From the look, it seems Google changed the login design (just that the screens look different).
However, I did not change any code for Google Login. It was working just fine till yesterday.

But now, I am able to login to my app through Google Login for the first time. But when I log out and try to do the Google login again, the WebView is just blank. There is no sign of the login page loading.

So, is there any new code snippet that needs to be added? 
I am using swift language.

Apparently I found this thread: [Google Sign In not working on iOS 10 Beta 7 with Xcode 8 beta 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091841/google-sign-in-not-working-on-ios-10-beta-7-with-xcode-8-beta-6?rq=1)

which is the exact issue I am facing. I tried the steps mentioned there too.

The interesting thing is that, we have a Google Signup and Login option separately and both are doing the same thing.
While login does not work after the first time, Sign up is working fine. No problems with that. Both the functionalities have same code too. 
Let me know if you require any additional details from me for helping me out!

Comment: Try to perform a "Project" > "Clean". Also check if google URLs that are required for google login are allowed in your AppTransportSecurity rules.

Comment: @Floler Hi. Tried this, unfortunately not able to resolve. I have edited my question to include another thread which mentions my issue. Tried those steps too but am unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Floler Please see the edited question for added details. Is there anything else you can suggest as a possible solution?