# com.facebook.sdk.login Code=308 "(null) on iOS10

Tags: ios, facebook, ios10, xcode8

In one of my project I have implemented FB login, which is working fine till iOS9 but in iOS10 its showing an error:-

```
com.facebook.sdk.login Code=308 "(null)
```

What can be the reason of this error.
Can anyone help me out with the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Facebook iOS SDK on iOS 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10)

Comment: Answer is described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10 Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In IOS 10 something (don't know exactly what) is changed with keychain. To resolve    this navigate to Targets->Capabilities and **enable keychain sharing**. 
[image]