# Xamarin Facebook iOS10 SDK com.facebook.sdk.login Code=308

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have just updated `Xamarin Studio` on Mac and `XCode` to the latest version with iOS 10 simulators.

In my application I have `Facebook` login integration, but after the update I'm getting an error:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.login Code=308 "(null)"
```

I've researched that this error is corrected by setting the "`Keychain Sharing`" on the "`Capabilities`" tab of the project in `XCode`.

Here: 
[How to use Facebook iOS SDK on iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10)

But `Xamarin Studio` doesn't seems to set this property right even setting it to `Entitlements.plist`

Is this the right solution to this problem or is there a different solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, I found the solution to this error doing the opposite of what is described here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39673/iphonesimulator-build-results-in-no-valid-ios-code-signing-keys-found-in-keychain

Basically, go to the Project Options > iOS Bundle Signing and add the Entitlements.plist at the "Custom Entitlements" text box. It works!

-- Julio

Answer (score 0):

Only happen on Simulator.

Solution: 
Select `Entitlements.plist` for Simulator Configuration, by default this field is empty.

[image]