# Facebook login issue with iOS 10

Tags: facebook, ios-simulator, facebook-login, ios10, xcode8

I use facebook to login into my application.
Trying to login using Facebook on `iOS 10`, iPhone simulator 6s.

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

10814 : kLSApplicationNotFoundErr
-10814  No application in the Launch Services database matches the input criteria.
```

I am using facebook sdk version **4.13.1.**
Before XCode 8, same code was working perfectly.

Any Help ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

Error status **10814** occurs basically when `cantOpenUrl`,which is used by the `facebook` to call the `url` using the arguments **fbauth2:/** .As suggested bt this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10),*printing happens inside this function so you cant do anything much with that*

Apple changed the way of working with IOS 10.To fix this issue you can go to

**Targets > Capabilities > Enable `Keychain` Sharing**

Here is a screenshot from the same thread linked above
[image]

As posted in this post the of the forums [developor](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50332) issues

The problem is with the **FBSDLoginManager** , the *completion handler* is never called

> so in **debuging**, the [author](https://forums.developer.apple.com/people/dev.hoha) put the **breakpoint** in "**FBSDKLoginManager.m" at "logInWithBehavior:     (FBSDKLoginBehavior)loginBehavior"** and **findout that weakSelf getting nil and not be able to call "logInWithBehavior: serverConfiguration:** serverConfigurationLoadError:"

```
   - (void)logInWithBehavior:(FBSDKLoginBehavior)loginBehavior  
    {  
      __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;  
      [FBSDKServerConfigurationManager loadServerConfigurationWithCompletionBlock:^(FBSDKServerConfiguration *serverConfiguration, NSError *loadError) {  
        [weakSelf logInWithBehavior:loginBehavior serverConfiguration:serverConfiguration serverConfigurationLoadError:loadError];  
      }];  
    }
```

**Solution 1:**

> Change *FBSDKLoginManager* variable as property rather than using as function variable. Make sure, *FBSDKLoginManager* variable **must remain alive** until the **completion handler call**

You can turn on the *-Wimplicit-retain-self* warning to get a warning if you reference *self* accidentally in a block.Posted in the [Github issues](https://github.com/facebook/KVOController/issues/82)

**Solution 2:**

You can add these to your plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>akamaihd.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
```

and also changing the **AppDelegate** as follows

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
     return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application,     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
{
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url,    options: options)
}
```

as suggested by [author](https://forums.developer.apple.com/people/mscherzer)
After this you can run your *swift3,SDK,ios10* on *XCode8*

Also check as mention by the [author](https://forums.developer.apple.com/people/da1) if the **Google Analytics** was adding its own controller on the top of your view controller by setting

> **Setting *"FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled"* to *"NO"* in the *-Info.plist* solved the problem.**

.

> **Full attribution goes to the [forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50332) and the authors mentioned in the forum**

Comment: hey i realized that somehow i downvoted your answer, and this clearly wasn't my intention. i even don't know how this happened and am trying to undo my vote but the system warns me that it's impossible to do it unless you edit your answer. so if you do it i'll upvote it. i apologize for any inconvenience!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have enabled Key Chain sharing in Capabilities-> KeyChain Sharing 
Enable Key chain sharing

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your *Info.plist* corresponds to **2. Whitelist Facebook Apps** section of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

For iOS Facebook SDK v.4.13 it should contain

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

These requirements were introduced for **iOS 9.x**.

Comment: You have no Facebook app installed on your Simulator, so this error informs you that iOS can't find it. In this case you should see a web-based login window.

Comment: Can you help in that, to run a web based login view. What happens is : 

I run app, press facebook button. A web based view opens and tells that you have already logged into facebook for this app. Then i click ok, view closes and facebook response error 308 comes. 

Any help ?

Comment: I have the exact same issue

Comment: @MradulKumar: I faced the same issue & here is the solution for that, You receive 308 error because in iOS 10 and later you have to enable "Keychain Sharing" under "Capabilities". Just try enabling it you are good to go. And please let me know if you find this solution helps solves the main question you posted here it will be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in you didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function in the appDelegate

FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

Comment: Can you explain your answer so that others can learn from it?