# Google Plus not working in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, google-plus

I Faced below issues for google plus can open url scheme in Xcode 8.1 with iOS 10

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.4.1://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
2016-11-21 16:05:58.229 googlePlus[16034:206474] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.4.0://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.4.0"
2016-11-21 16:05:58.238 googlePlus[16034:206474] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.3.0://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
2016-11-21 16:05:58.240 googlePlus[16034:206474] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.2.0://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
2016-11-21 16:05:58.242 googlePlus[16034:206474] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
2016-11-21 16:05:58.243 googlePlus[16034:206474] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "hasgplus4://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme hasgplus4"
```

Comment: have you ON KEYCHAIN SHARING

Comment: No. Why you told on keychain sharing

Comment: because in ios 10 there is required

Comment: Thanks Working fine @NarendraPandey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error **10814** is for,

> No application in the Launch Services database matches the input
>   criteria

Apple changed some api calls methods from ios 10.

For resolve this you can refer this link,

[error 10814](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40191999/6742121)

Hope this will help you.