# Facebook Login Overlay - iOS not working

Tags: ios

I'm trying to make my user login using Facebook. If they are not logged in, my app brings up an overlay view that forces the user to login. This is how I do that:

```
    self.overlay.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

    loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    self.loginButton.delegate = self
    self.loginButton.center = self.overlay.center
    self.overlay.addSubview(self.loginButton)

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(overlay)
```

The login button shows up and covers the whole screen, which is exactly what I want, but then once the user clicks on the login button, it doesn't bring up the login page as expected. I believe this is because the overlay is covering it. The console prints this error:

> "canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

2017-12-03 17:05:02.683700-0800 FinalProject[3093:58095]" I'm completely stumped here. Not sure if it's relevant, but this is within a TableViewController.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to enable Keychain Sharing.
Follow instructions on this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40191999/3692511