# How to add keychain sharing feature to App ID without device?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, facebook

My problem is that I need to enable the keychain sharing feature to App ID in order to make Facebook login work for iOS10. [How to use Facebook iOS SDK on iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10)

However, I get the below message. [image]

**I have NO iPhone device.** However, I do have a paid for developers account. I don't need a provisioning profile to resolve this error, do I?

How exactly can this be resolved?

Comment: Yes, you need a provisioning profile in the developer portal even if you are only running it on the simulator.

Comment: @Paulw11 how to get one without a device??

Comment: Sorry, I said provisioning profile. I should have said app id - as it shows in the screenshot.  You can create an app id in the developer portal.

Comment: How to add the keychain sharing feature to the App ID though?

Comment: You don't need to worry about adding it to the app id if you are only building for the simulator since there is no code signing performed for simulator builds.  You can ignore the "add the keychain Sharing feature to your app id"

Answer (score 16):

Restarting the xcode fixes the issue ! I hate you apple :)

Comment: Thanks. In XCode you always stumble upon such things. It's so irritating ;) I wish they learn from Android Studio

Comment: make sure that are signing with appleid id in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "general" tab and look at the "signing" section.  I had been signed in at a Corporate account (which has since expired) and so had to select my correct account from the "Team" drop-down menu.  Now the Team can be found in the Account.