# How to fix invalid code signing entitlements issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I created new certificate and distribution provisioning file to upload binary for testflight.

I am getting this error during validate my binary.
[image]

Here is a screenshot for apple id.
[image]

and here is a screenshot for xcode.
[image]

How can I fix it? Thanks for answers.

Comment: Show your app capabilities, Xcode->App->Targets->Capabilities.

Comment: thanks for reply. I updated the question with screenshot.

Comment: Try to restart your Xcode, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781950/how-to-add-keychain-sharing-feature-to-app-id-without-device)

Comment: already tried but not fixed

Comment: Are you using automatic manage signing on?

Comment: no, I set it manually

Comment: Recommended using the automatic manage signing, Xcode version?