# Facebook Login Swift iOS 10 - Nothing Works

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm running the most recent version of XCode and Swift. I'm trying to implement Facebook Login; however, I keep on running into persistent errors.

First I am getting this:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

I implemented the solutions listed here **yet still no luck**.
[How to use Facebook iOS SDK on iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10)

I've tried double checking Keychain Access On, Reinstalling FacebookSDK, implementing it in various different ways such as: http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/05/facebook-login-swift-language-ios but I can't seem to get around this.

Here is my login result: `Optional(<FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult: 0x170251550>`

Not sure if that is right. Also I get this error though I don't have network loss on and my wifi is perfectly connected. `Could not successfully update network info during initialization.`

```
    @IBAction func fbLoginButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
            print("Here is the result", result)
            print("Here is the error" , error)

            if (error == nil){
                print("the error is nil")
                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
                //commenting if statement out temporarily for debugging purposes

//                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
//                {
                print("email is contained and printing result")
                self.getFBUserData()
                fbLoginManager.logOut()
//                }
            }
        }
    }

    func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                print("inside get FB user data")
                if (error == nil){
                    self.dict = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                    print(result!)
                    print(self.dict)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Why is this occurring and how can this be resolved?

Comment: You r not logged in to facebook through your app Right? If yes then I will make a small demo of it and reply to you if working or not.

Comment: Check my answer. I have tested code in my demo and its working perfectly I got result.

Comment: If you want demo please give me your Email Id, I will mailed it to you

Comment: Hey Jecky, thanks so much for your help. I really appreciate your responsiveness! I think I figured it out with this 
https://gist.github.com/codegefluester/f797dd723e93e545b855525a4b9ab057

Comment: @Jecky let's keep in touch for iOS collaboration and work: rrtigga@ucdavis.edu what's your email id?

Comment: My email id is : Modijecky@gmail.com or Jiten.benzatine@gmail.com. I am ready to work with you.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code is perfect but you have to Enable Keychain access for Facebook Login in

That will solve your problem

[image]

Comment: I run your code and it gives me output successfully. If you want demo then  i will forward to you. Did you set your fb app id in plist file?

Answer (score 1):

I realized the problem was in the App Delegate https://gist.github.com/codegefluester/f797dd723e93e545b855525a4b9ab057

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            app,
            open: url as URL!,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )
    }

    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            application,
            open: url as URL!,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
    }
}
```