# facebook authentication in ios10

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

when I am trying to login with facebook in ios 10 got this error

-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)".

Kindly help me out to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Facebook iOS SDK on iOS 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10)

Answer (score 1):

This is an Xcode warning indicating the the canOpenURL: call returned false. As long as you have configured the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry in your plist as described above, you can ignore this warning you can check this link for the total info : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9 , in which u can see what exactly to add in your plist in steps hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to on Keychain Sharing flag under TARGETS->Capabilities->Keychain Sharing.

[image]

Comment: I think this will not solve the problem of this warning. You will get this warning though you enable keychain