# Facebook iOS integration throws error iOS 10.1

Tags: ios, facebook, url

I am getting error for facebook integration in iOS. See the error below:

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
>
> My AppDelegate code:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary *)options {
    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                               sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                      annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [FIRApp configure];

    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = [FIRApp defaultApp].options.clientID;
//    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;

    /* Push Notification enable code(remove commented code it will allow punotification popup)*/
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
        UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
        | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
        | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
         requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
         completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
         }
         ];

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        [[FIRMessaging messaging] setRemoteMessageDelegate:self];
#endif
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

    return YES;

}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {



    if ([LISDKCallbackHandler shouldHandleUrl:url]) {
        return [LISDKCallbackHandler application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
    }
    else if ([url.scheme hasPrefix:@"fb"])
    {
        return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                              openURL:url
                                                    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                           annotation:annotation];
    }
    else
    {

        return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                                   sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                          annotation:annotation];
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to post some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Facebook iOS SDK on iOS 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10)