# FB SDK Error: Login Failed (react-native)

Tags: ios, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I'm currently setting up Facebook Authentication for my Reach Native application. After the usual problems with the react-native-fbsdk setup, now the Facebook App Events work and the LoginManager loads up.

My problem: After Authorisation the LoginManager redirects me back to the app, then shows me the Error:

> Login Failed

I'm using the very standard LoginManager implementation:

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  LoginManager,
  AccessToken,
} = FBSDK;


export default class FacebookAuth extends Component {

  facebook(){
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(
  function(result) {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      alert('Login cancelled');
    } else {
      alert('Login success with permissions: '
        +result.grantedPermissions.toString());
    }
  },
  function(error) {
    alert('Login fail with error: ' + error);
  }
);
```

Do you have any pointers for me?

I already checked:

- FB app info in Info.Plist
- iOS Bundle ID in Facebook App
- Client OAuth Settings
- FBSDK LoginButton (same error)

I'm running: iOS 10 & react-native 0.38.0.

Thanks!

Comment: I added Keychain Sharing, LoginManager.logOut() before Login but nothing was solving for me.

What solved was using Facebook SDK 4.38.0 instead of latest (Facebook SDK 4.39.0)

Answer (score 67):

[Error when login with Facebook SDK — React Native](https://medium.com/@crysfel/error-when-login-with-facebook-sdk-react-native-c06a33078102)

> The problem was that Facebook SDK was still keeping the previous session token, and when I was trying to login again I was getting this error, to solve this problem all I had to do was to call the logOut method from the LoginManager.

try to this before `LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions...`

```
LoginManager.logOut();
```

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of time. Thanks Yifan.

Comment: That really helps me dude

Comment: That didn't worked for me, and it is just happening on iOS

Comment: I added Keychain Sharing, LoginManager.logOut() before Login but nothing was solving for me. What solved was using Facebook SDK 4.38.0 instead of latest (Facebook SDK 4.39.0)

Comment: LoginManager.logOut() thanks its working .

Answer (score 4):

After couple of hours trying different solutions, I managed to fix it thanks to  Cassiano Montanari and zavadpe's comment from here [Incorrect installation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/416#issuecomment-438306479)

I ended up with this configuration:

Pod file:

```
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.38.0'
  pod 'FacebookSDK', '4.38.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '4.38.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.38.0'
```

You need to make sure you add `libRCTFBSDK.a` in Link Binary With Libraries and to remove `'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'` from your pod file.

My issue start ocurring after I upgrade FBSDK to 4.39 and I couldn't find any way to specify the SDK version into the pod file if I use `pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'`.

I think one option is to use [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage), but I haven't try it yet.

Answer (score 3):

As per Cassiano Montanari's comment, downgrading from 4.39.0 to 4.38.0 is the fix. I was struggling with this all afternoon and the downgrade solved it immediately.

Comment: I experienced the same thing with RN 0.57.5.

Comment: Worked for me too. Wild bug!

Answer (score -1):

I think, I resolved the issue.
I'm still not 100% clear why, but it related to this:
[How to use Facebook iOS SDK on iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10)

After enabling keychain access, the authentication works.

Comment: I added Keychain Sharing, LoginManager.logOut() before Login but nothing was solving for me. What solved was using Facebook SDK 4.38.0 instead of latest (Facebook SDK 4.39.0)