# React Native Post image with hashtag to facebook

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to post an image with hashtag to facebook using react-native-fbsdk(0.4.0) like this:

```
ShareDialog.canShow(shareContent)
  .then(canShow => {
    if (canShow) {
      return ShareDialog.show(shareContent);
    } else {
      return Promise.reject('error sharing');
    }
 })
 .then(result => {
   // evaluating result here
 });
```

Share dialog appears normally and content is posted to FB when `shareContent` has the following content:

```
shareContent = {
  contentType: 'photo',
  photos: [{
    imageUrl: 'valid uri'
  }]
};
```

When I add a hashtag, share dialog doesn't appear and `result` is an empty object `{}`:

```
shareContent = {
  contentType: 'photo',
  commonParameters: {
    hashtag: '#SomeHashTag'
  },
  photos: [{
    imageUrl: 'the same valid uri'
  }]
};
```

Also if I try to add a hashtag to other types like `link` share dialog works fine.

What I am doing wrong? :(

Comment: I've an external image URL. How do I convert it into a local URI to send using Facebook Share?

Comment: Did you find out how? When I use "#myhashtag" the dialog doesn't open, when I use "myhashtag" the hashtag doesn't show up in the dialog or in the shared content later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same problem. I wrote printF for displaying what happens inside FBSDKSharePhoto. And I noticed next info:

> canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

Then I've googled [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10) and install facebook app on Iphone and loggedIn  (you can't install facebook on emulator device you need use real device for this)
And it works for me.