# SwiftyDropBox OSStatus error 10814 Swift 3

Tags: swift3, swiftydropbox, osstatus

I've been researching all over trying to fix this issue to no avail. I followed the SwiftyDropBox tutorial thoroughly and had everything working. It's now not working and I'm not sure why. Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10) and this [link](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-10814), the error is supposed to be related to not having the DropBox app installed. That's fine. In the tutorial it says:

> If you wish to authenticate via the in-app webview, then set browserAuth to NO. Otherwise, authentication will be done via an external web browser.

I set that parameter to false and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that I already had a viewcontroller being presented. It looks like the dropbox authorization acts as a "presentation". It worked once I dismissed the viewcontroller. Those error messages still appear but according to this [post](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/ios9-canOpenURL-failed-for-URL-quot-dbapi-2/td-p/130055) it's normal behavior. I wish they'd have more descriptive messages.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is displayed when native Dropbox app is not installed in the phone and can be ignored. See [response from Dropbox forum](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/DBChooser-is-not-supported-iOS10-0/td-p/191884)