# Can't get access token in Xcode Swift Facebook login SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift3

I'm trying to test Facebook SDK login in my app but keep getting this error. I see a dialog which accepts my email and password to login and then tells me I have already accepted the app. I should see a message "Logged in but I only see the error below. How can I test the Facebook SDK in the Xcode iOS simulator. I tested this on an iPhone with an alert to display the access token but got the same result. It will always present "User cancelled login".

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.) User cancelled login.
```

Here is my code.

```
func signInWithFacebook(button: UIButton) {

    let loginManager = LoginManager()

    loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile ], viewController: self) { loginResult in

        switch loginResult {

        case .failed(let error):

            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Login error", message: error as? String, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let okAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action -> Void in }

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            print(error)

        case .cancelled:

            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Login cancelled", message: "User cancelled login", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let okAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action -> Void in }

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            print("User cancelled login.")

        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):

            print(grantedPermissions)

            print(declinedPermissions)

            print(accessToken)

            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Login success", message: String(describing: accessToken), preferredStyle: .alert)

            let okAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action -> Void in }

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            print("Logged in")
        }
    }
}
```

On the first pass, I got the Facebook login dialog but thereafter I just see a dialog saying I have already authorized my app with an OK button.

```
let accessToken = AccessToken.current
```

in viewDidLoad() returns nil always. I need to get an accessToken so i can send it to an API and test the response.

Comment: are you there ?

Comment: yes, I am here.

Comment: Do you want to access user info ?

Comment: I don't need the user info but I do need the token and the other variables set by login .success. I want to send the token to an API for login there.

Comment: Are you got access token while authenticate ?

Comment: No, it always returns nil. I can never get my code to print "Logged in". It is always "User cancelled login".

Comment: did your fb redirect to your automatically while your authentication complete.?  or you have pressed Done button on login page ?

Comment: Yes, I attached an image to the question. It always returns "User cancelled login" after I click Done.

Comment: you have pressed OK button?

Comment: Yes, I press OK and then Done and then I just get "User cancelled login".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42266558/5461400

Comment: Can you provide some more info about your edit to that answer please? Line number #94 reads as this `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:key];`

Comment: in any case, I would have thought the dialog above should give me ,success rather than .cancelled.

Comment: @markhorrocks In the Facebook app settings page, have you made your app public?

Comment: Yes., the app is public and I get no warnings that it is not. I am using this guide for setup and there is no mention of any other settings developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add this function in my AppDelegate.swift. It seems completely undocumented.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
                                                                     open: url,
                                                                     sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                                     annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

mb for fb login only better use [FacebookLogin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/getting-started)

token here:

```
FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString
```

Comment: actually  `let token = accessToken.authenticationToken`

Comment: hm. interesting, but on one my project i see: `    func loginButtonDidCompleteLogin(_ loginButton: LoginButton, result: LoginResult){
        switch result {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("Cancelled")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print("Logged In", FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
            ...
            }
        }
    }` and its works! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Error status 10814 is related to `cantOpenUrl`, which is used when Facebook call the URL using the arguments fbauth2:/. Like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10). Printing happens inside this function so you can't do anything much with that

You can also change this in Settings:

> Targets > Capabilities > Enable Keychain Sharing

It doesn't matter because you are testing in the Simulator and it will not be coming when you will test in a real device.

Comment: I need to test this on a simulator as I need to send the facebook access token to an api for login there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already added to CFBundleURLSchemes in your Info.plist to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.

> If you are trying to resolve "canOpenURL: failed" warnings, those only
>   indicate that the Facebook app is not installed on your device or
>   simulator and can be ignored.

Comment: How can I install the facebook app on a simulator?

Comment: you dont need to install you need to just ignore this warning in simulator.

Comment: Is it possible to install the app? I need to obtain the access token and send it to an API then test the response.

Comment: try to authenticate your app in simulator . you will get access token with this warning.

Comment: @markhorrocks I think you already getting the access token! That's why you were able to log in. Yes, as KKRocks is saying just ignore this message. Everything is working fine!

Comment: Surely it should print "Logged In"? I see a message saying I have already authorized the app and an OK button.

Comment: let accessToken = AccessToken.current returns nil