# -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)

Tags: ios

i'm adding Facebook signup in my application, i got this issue

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
>    Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug

this is my appDelegate

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.19, green: 0.18, blue: 0.31, alpha: 1.0)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]


        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        )
    }
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            app,
            open: url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
            annotation: nil
        )
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
}
```

and this is my info.plsit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb1835000000000000</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>1835000000000000</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>FoodTasker</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- SDK v4.34.0
- iOS SDK   10.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Facebook iOS SDK on iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10) ... found via a google search for `"OSStatus error -10814"`

Comment: thanks for reply. i check the link you have post it says :
"It happens because Apple changed the way of working with keychain in iOS 10. To fix this issue you simply should go to Targets->Capabilities and enable keychain sharing (it enables access to keychain for your app)"
i did that but still not working

Comment: Are you running this on the Simulator or on a Device?

Comment: I'm using Simulator

Comment: Quick searching seems to indicate it won't work on Simulator, because FB is not installed. Do a google search for `"fbauth2" "OSStatus error -10814" "simulator"` ... lots of results... you should be able to either find a solution or confirm it won't work on simulator.

Comment: sure i Will do thank you

Answer (score 2):

now I used the latest pod version and I have followed below steps
1) Add comment code in pod file like below code

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

2) Open terminal and go in Project directory then run followed command

```
pod install
above code will removed Facebook SDK from project
```

3) Uncomment 1 step code then reinstall facebook library. It will install latest veriosn facebook SDK and try to run again. Issue will solved :)

Thank you